# Can i have two keys with the same name in Map?

Tags: java

im trying to create a `TreeMap`. with Character as key.
im trying to create it by running on a Vector of type Person.
and get the first letter from the person name and put it as key in the Map.
for example:
i have 4 persons, their name starts with P.
i want to run on the vector, and create a `Map` that the key is P.

```
public class Phonebook{
    static Vector<Map<Character, Vector<Person>>> mapVector = new Vector<>();

public void makePhonebook(){
        Iterator<Person> personIterator =  PeopleDets.getPersons().iterator();
        while (personIterator.hasNext()){
            Person temp = (Person)personIterator.next();
            mapVector.add(new TreeMap<>().put((temp.getName().charAt(0)), );
        }

    }
```

my question is, will it create 1 `Map` for P letter and with more code will create a Vector of persons starts with P, or create like 4 Map with P as key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can i have two keys with the same name in Map?

No. A `Map` requires all keys to be unique. Please check the documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

A new duplicate key will overwrite the value of the previous duplicate key e.g.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("A", "Apple");
        map.put("A", "Anchor");
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{A=Anchor}
```

Comment: so if i do it like that, it will create one Map with this key? or will it throw an excpetion?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO. However, based on the example you provided, you can take a look at [Tries](https://medium.com/basecs/trying-to-understand-tries-3ec6bede0014). Or consider a sorted list, if the phone book is not a very large collection.

Comment: Whatever you were trying to link to does not work...